# How do I show what I have selcted?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

Selected objects no longer light up yellow when selected. I'm assuming that this is a setting that got tuned off somehow and not a glitch. Where is the setting that turns back on the selection highlighting?

2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm that you have not disabled the general **Show Overlays button** .......

[image]

Comment: That was the problem. Somehow the whole thing got shut off. Is there a hotkey for it? I'm accidentally causing all sorts of things to go wrong because I can never keep all the hotkeys straight.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Overlays popover in the *3D View* header turn on *Outline Selected*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like that's already turned on. I tried turning it off and on again, but still no outlines.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can enter **Local Mode** (shortcut = forwardslash <kbd>/</kbd>)
That will hide all objects except for the selected one.